# Html.TextboxFor not binding to my model Properties in View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a View that is returned by and action Method from a controller like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   return View()
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection form)
{
}
```

I want them to be done in a single View like So:

```
@model Models.RegistrationViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
{
   @Html.TextboxFor(model.User.Username )
}
```

but the problem is i cant bind my textboxfor to the models Properties.. How can i consume a single view for post and get in my scenario..

Comment: This is a great example. How could I accomplish this more than 1 file upload? For example, a grid with multiple rows of file uploads. I basically want to create a collection of upload files and pass this to the controller on form submit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You usage of `@Html.Textbox(model.User.Username)` means that you generating a textbox with a `name` attribute equal to the value `Username` which would not bind to a model. If the value of `UserName` where say `John` it would generate

```
<input type="text" name="John" id="John" value />
```

Change it to

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User.Username)
```

which will generate the correct `name` attribute which relates to you model

```
<input type="text" name="User.Username" id="User_Username" value="John" />
```

Then change the POST method signature to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(RegistrationViewModel model)
```

so that the model is bound and its values correctly set.

Note also the method is named `Create()` so in your view it needs to be

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" })
```

Comment: i slightly change my model. I forgot to set its property i was looking for the [HttPost] attribute

Answer (score 3):

The action in the Beginform should be the same name as the action method:

also, pass the model to the action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(RegistrationViewModel pMyModel)
{
     string tUsername= pMyModel.User.Username;
}
```

also you need a submit button inside the form to apply the post action:

```
@model Models.RegistrationViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
{
   @Html.TextboxFor(m => m.model.User.Username )

<input value="create" type="submit"/>
}
```

Comment: whic will be the post. I tried that but is not working\

Comment: The action in the Beginform should be the same name as the action method. I have updated the answer

Comment: still no luck. By the way my model was a complex nested class. It says it has a User class within it as its property. is it possible to do that